# NoClassDefFound error after ADT update

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I recently updated my ADT to version 23.0 from 22. Now my project which used to run fine before the update gives me the following error:-

```
  01-01 10:19:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mapps.dailystatusupdater.StatusUpdate
01-01 10:19:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at com.mapps.dailystatusupdater.SplashScreen$RefreshTokenTask.onPostExecute(SplashScreen.java:253)
```

SplashScreen.java

```
private class RefreshTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /**
             * Check if access token is expired
             * Request new  access token  by passing refresh token 
             */
            // DoInBackground code
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, StatusUpdate.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
```

AndroidManifest.java

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mapps.dailystatusupdater.StatusUpdate"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

[image]

I also checked my Android libraries to export from the import/export settings.
HOw can I resolve this? Thank you

Comment: try doing right click on project -> Android tools -> Fix project properties

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I did that. Still the same error. My other projects are running fine

Comment: try cleaning. then delete all content inside bin folder. clean again

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I did it now the project gets a red cross on the folder and I cant run the project, Still the same error

Comment: now check you will see error in internal folder or else checkout project properties java build path.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
Project -> Libs -> Right click on Jar file -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path
```

and

```
Project -> Right Click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> and Check that library -> OK  -> Clean the Project.
```

Comment: if you added any jar.

Comment: i have added the image for my libraries and all are checked

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and make sure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project . Clean all projects

And one more thing - goto android sdk manager make sure you have android build tools installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already done the same. I have also provided a image of how my build path window looks like in the question

Comment: Restart the eclipse and make one sample project and see the new project has the same isue or not?

Comment: I tried creating new project but I got the following error `eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

Error
Thu Jan 01 12:04:24 IST 2015
Failed to load properties file for project 'temp'`